# virtual-scroll returning empty Array

Tags: angular, typescript, virtualscroll

HTML:

```
<virtual-scroll [items]="items" (update)="viewPortItems = $event">    
                <div *ngFor="let item of viewPortItems">
                  {{item.name}}
                </div>                    
</virtual-scroll>
```

In component i am initializing the items.
Component:

```
items = [{
        name: 'xyz'
    },
    {
        name: 'xyz'
    },
    {
        name: 'xyz'
    },
    {
        name: 'xyz'
    }
]
```

But in my page nothing is displayed. viewPortItems is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, in my case i solved it but  adjusting the height of the virtual-scroll element. 
You can always debug this kind of behavior in your element tab => adjust element style.

Comment: It's a solution to work for me. Thanks. I use Angular 9

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of viewPortItems" [item]="item">
```

and make a slight change:

```
{{item?.name}}
```

Comment: If i do like that getting error

zone.js:192 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'item' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("s = $event">

Comment: yes you are right, no need for `[item]="item"` , i think there is a problem with items initialization

Comment: My application is angular5. i installed angular2 virtual scroll. Is it the problem?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the version. Angular 2 is the same as Angular 2+ or Angular 2-6. Only AngularJS/Angular 1 is not compatible with the later versions. Do you have VirtualScrollModule and CommonModule (for *ngIf) in your module's imports?

Answer (score -1):

My guess is you are not sizing the virtual scroll container. Any of the virtual scroll implementations don't work if the container is not sized in some way, add style=’height: 300px’ and see if it works..

See https://medium.com/@andrew_54539/virtualization-of-ngfor-welcome-to-the-pure-ngfor-replacement-ngvfor-21254034acbc?source=linkShare-40e7ef73f7e0-1535661741

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read the [How do I write a good answer guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in order to help this user to solve this user.